# Boxplot Not Showing Correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter, aesthetics

Attempting to run this command:

```
data %>%
+     ggplot( aes(x=Seconds, y=Rate)) +
+     geom_boxplot( fill="skyblue", notch=FALSE) +
+     geom_jitter( size=1, color="orange", width=0.2)
```

On this data.frame (each column has been transformed to a factor) (simplified):

```
Seconds  |  Rate
0.512849 |  0
0.227982 |  0
1.287198 |  1
1.278101 |  1
2.218711 |  2
3.124897 |  2
5.128947 |  3
6.189710 |  3
```

Output is this, which is showing the scatter plot part correctly but not the box-plot part:

[image: Plot with error described in post.]

Comment: Take a look at the docs: the expectation is that your `x` argument is discrete, such as the rate you have. You probably want to switch your x & y axes. Why do you have seconds as a factor? That seems like the opposite of what you'd want

Comment: Also take a look at `str(data)`. I think you'll find that `seconds` is showing up as a character or factor (while you want it to be a continuous number), probably as a result of the import process from whatever file you read it in from.

Comment: Hi folks, I've tried swapping axes, and I reverted the change on `seconds` so it's just ints. I also followed JMilner's advice and removed the pipe, and added in the group and put `data` within the ggplot() function. Still same result I'm afraid. Looks like this now:

`ggplot(data, aes(x=Rate, y=Seconds, group=Seconds)) +
    geom_boxplot( fill="skyblue", notch=FALSE) +
    geom_jitter( size=1, color="orange", width=0.2)`

Image: https://imgur.com/a/8M0tKIi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers were all partly correct, but the full answer is below. In particular the data needed grouped by Rate (JMilner suggested the grouping but by Seconds, so was on the right track!), and Rate needed to be made a factor, not seconds (as Brian and Camille suggested)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Rate, y=Seconds, group=Rate)) +
+     geom_boxplot( fill="skyblue", notch=FALSE) +
+     geom_jitter( size=1, color="orange", width=0.3)
```

Final output looks like this (changed Seconds to Minutes, label is now correct:)[image]

Answer (score 1):

geom_boxplot require a `group=` command inside `aes()`

It will default to your x values unless you specify another variable.

So to add it...

```
data %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=Seconds, y=Rate, group=Seconds)) +
  geom_boxplot( fill="skyblue", notch=FALSE) +
  geom_jitter( size=1, color="orange", width=0.2)
```

Also you will note that I removed the `+` at the start of every line. You only need this at the end OR the start - not both.

Not sure why you are using the pipe either (`%>%`) but you could just plot it like so...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Seconds, y=Rate, group=Seconds)) +
  geom_boxplot( fill="skyblue", notch=FALSE) +
  geom_jitter( size=1, color="orange", width=0.2)
```

So here you have a boxplot for every value in your seconds column, which looks like it is different at every row.

Your boxplot groups should be the variable on the x axis and typically they should be categorical, or at least an integer.

Numerically, it would make more sense if you had the values in the Rate column as the grouping values for the boxes - although I understand rate is probably a dependent variable here.

I think you need to give the question a bit more context, but hopefully this helps.